# Qt Resource System rcc options and bz2?

Tags: qt, compression

My application needs a 12 MB text file as a built-in resource. I was surprised the resulting executable was a little over 12 MB, so I tried zip on the command line and it only deflated 68% which is below the 70% threshold.

bz2 deflates it smaller. Is there a way I can use that compression, or something even better? I'm sure plain text files used to compress really well.

I'm not clear about reducing the 'threshold' in the Makefile. `rcc -h` says:

```
--threshold <level>  Threshold to consider compressing files.
```

So would that translate to `--threshold="70%"`?

Comment: This is where Qt coders complain about the lack of a proper compression API. `qCompress` does not count.

Answer (score 0):

First, the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/rcc.html) on the `-threshold` flag:

> Specifies a threshold level (as a percentage) to use when deciding whether to compress a file. If the reduction in the file size is greater than the threshold level, it is compressed; otherwise, the uncompressed data is stored instead. The default threshold level is 70%, meaning that compressed files which are 30% or less of their original size are stored as compressed data.

Based on a read, you have two choices: use the default zlib compression and manually set the threshold, or set the compression level yourself.

To increase the compression level to max:

```
rcc -level 9 ...
```

or to raise the compression threshold *just* enough:

```
rcc -threshold 35% ...
```

You can combine the two, of course. The default compression level is -1, meaning zlib decides how much it compresses.

**Edit**: the documentation contradicts itself (or is perhaps simply not clear) when discussing compression. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#compression) it uses integral values instead of a percentage for the `-threshold` flag:

```
rcc -compress 2 -threshold 3
```

Some testing is called for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Jon. I tested by adding a mass of whitespace to my file. Enough to get the deflation reported by command line zip to 71% and the executable produced was down to 4.6 MB, so the theory is right.

rcc only seems to produce an XML like output, but accepts -threshold and -compress options. Any values seem acceptable without syntax error report.

I'm not sure where to put the threshold option in the makefile. The part referencing my file:

`qrc_meresource.o: qrc_meresource.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o qrc_meresource.o qrc_meresource.cpp`

I've tried putting rcc acceptable options at various places. All rejected.

This line defines CXXFLAGS:
`CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)`

I even tried changing the 'COMPRESS = gzip -9f' line to 'COMPRESS = bzip2 -9f', but the result was no different.

Comment: Getting it today. Commands like 'rcc -threshold 50 -binary res.qrc -o res.bin', or 'rcc -threshold 50 res.qrc -o res.cpp' work as required. Thanks again.